# Error code with a simple Java Serialization

Tags: java, serialization

I have a lump of code that is trying to do a simple binary tree '20 questions game'.

It's a first year project and implemented with a very simple yes-no binary tree.

The error is:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: Node
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at Game.main(Game.java:41)
```

I did an extensive search for this error however it was very hard to find ones that weren't chuncks of massive amounts of errors in some online forum.

Can anyone with experienc eof serialisation offer any more simple errors I might be fecking up?

```
try
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("tree.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        out.writeObject(rootnode);
        out.close();
```

is the example block the error points to.

Complete noob here.

Comment: I would recommend that you read up on Java serialization. Here is one tutorial: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/

Comment: Does the `Node` implement `Serializable`?

Comment: Is Node implements Serializable ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Node`s need to implement the `Serializable` Interface.
MAke sure you understand what a "`serializationID`" is and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like below on `Node` class:

```
class Node implements java.io.Serializable {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serialize objects, then the classes of those objects need to implement the `Serializable` interface. The error message tells you that your class `Node` does not implement the `Serializable` interface. Fixing this is very easy, change your class `Node`:

```
class Node implements Serializable {
    // ...
}
```

The `Serializable` interface has no methods (it's a *marker interface*); you don't have to implement any methods, just make the class implement the interface.

To make it complete, your class should also have a `serialVersionUID` variable.

See [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) (old, but still relevant) about serialization.

Note that not only your class `Node`, but also all the classes of the member variables of class `Node` must also implement `Serializable`.